# React-Three-Fiber Drei canvas not updating/leaving ghost image when route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

## The Problem

I currently have a canvas that covers the entire screen that renders a torus on the home page to a `View` that tracks to a `div` in the home page. However, when I click on my navbar to another page and the route changes, the torus is still there even when the `div` that the `View` is tracking disappears. The HTML elements position themselves as if the `div` is not there and upon refreshing the page, the torus disappears.

[Torus appearing correctly on the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XThB1.png)
This is the torus appear correctly on the home page. See that the "Home" text appears underneath it

[Torus staying there even though route changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zxuD.png)
This is the torus staying there even when the route changed. See that the "Syllabus" text appears at the top

[Refreshing the page, the torus is correctly not there on the syllabus page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dWtl.png)
When the page is refreshed, the torus disappears which is the intended response.

## Attempted Solutions

I making the `View` change depending on the route by inserting a `<Route>` inside the Canvas, but I couldn't do it as it wasn't a Three component.

I also tried to use `useLocation()` and the `useEffect()` components to update the position of the torus repeatedly, moving my canvas into its own element and nesting it inside the Routes component. However, I could not find a way to pass multiple references down to the Canvas.

I suspect the issue is because the canvas does not get rerendered when the route changes, however I'm not sure how to force a rerender.

## Code

Here is my code

```js
  const ref = useRef()
  const splashView = useRef()

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div ref={ref}>
          <Navbar/>
          <Routes>
            <Route index element={<Home ref={splashView}/>}/>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home ref={splashView}/>}/>
            <Route path="/syllabus" element={<Syllabus/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <Canvas eventSource={ref} className={styles.canvas}>
        {/* --------------Home Page-------------- */}
        <View track={splashView}>
          <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
          <directionalLight color="red" position={[0, 0, 5]} />
          <mesh>
            <torusGeometry/>
            <meshStandardMaterial />
          </mesh>
        </View>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After passing the reference into the component, I use `forwardRef()` to forward it to a div. I am using react-router-dom for routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you could just render the `Canvas` *with* the `Home` component on its route, and redirect the root index route to `"/home"` so the code is more ***DRY*** (*or vice-versa*).

```
const ref = useRef()
const splashView = useRef()

return (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div ref={ref}>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
          <Route
            path="/home"
            element={(
              <>
                <Home ref={splashView} />
                <Canvas eventSource={ref} className={styles.canvas}>
                  <View track={splashView}>
                    <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
                    <directionalLight color="red" position={[0, 0, 5]} />
                    <mesh>
                      <torusGeometry />
                      <meshStandardMaterial />
                    </mesh>
                  </View>
                </Canvas>
              </>
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/syllabus" element={<Syllabus />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This would work but I need the canvas to render things on other pages as well. Is it okay to have multiple canvas components each under a different route or would that create unnecessary bloat?

Comment: @Cookie That seems logical. I think you could also just incorporate the canvas directly in each routed component you are rendering as well, which would make the router code more clean.